# Get registered activities on Uber Cadence

Tags: java, cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I'm working on a project that uses Uber Cadence Java Client. How can I get the list of registered activities from the code?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell more about What is your use case ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such API at the moment. It could be added easily if that’s really needed. For now users should be responsible for maintaining what are registered in the worker.

// I may update this answer in the future if this changes.